# Why am I getting error unwrapping Optional if it has a value?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell, option-type

I’m banging my head against a wall trying to set an image from the contents of a URL.

The image is inside a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. I have created an outlet for it by dragging the `UIImage` view to the cell controller. In my collection controller, I’m trying to set the image to an external image like thi:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://yourfightsite-vod.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/posters/543e80b7aec51.jpg") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            cell.posterImage.image = image
        } else {
            println("Did not get image")
        }
    } else {
        println("Did not get NSData")
    }
} else {
    println("Did not get NSURL")
}
```

The reason for all of the `if let` lines is because somewhere it’s giving me the following error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

But can’t for the life of me find out where. If I print the `image` constant’s value, I get an `Optional` with what I guess is a pointer to that image in memory:

```
<UIImage: 0x788990d0>, {1754, 2480}
```

The two numeric values also seem to map to the external image’s width and height in pixels, respectively.

So what’s going? Why can’t I just set a bloody image in my collection cell view?!

**EDIT:** Entire method:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VODTitleCollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    cell.onDemandTitle = results[indexPath.row]

    if let url = NSURL(string: "https://yourfightsite-vod.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/posters/543e80b7aec51.jpg") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                print(image)
                print(cell.posterImage)
                cell.posterImage?.image = image
            } else {
                println("Did not get image")
            }
        } else {
            println("Did not get NSData")
        }
    } else {
        println("Did not get NSURL")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Did you already try this: `cell.posterImage?.image = image`? Maybe the cell isn't setup correctly.

Comment: I believe this is an asynchronous issue. http://natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/

Comment: Oh, yes, you should not do this on the main thread. Like never!

Comment: @dasdom I know this, I’m going through the Swift course on iTunes U which advocates downloading images in another thread. But I’m just trying it in the Simulator with a one-cell collection, and I’m getting the issues above. So would like to resolve it here first before wrapping it up to dispatch on another queue (and introducing complexity which would make debugging even more difficult).

Comment: @MartinBean Have you seen my other comment?

Comment: @dasdom Yes. It had no effect. The cells just have the default grey background (that I set above). The image doesn’t get rendered in the view.

Comment: Please check if the `posterImage` imageView is nil at this point. For example using the debugger.

Comment: @dasdom Okey-dokey, getting somewhere. `cell.posterImage` is `nil`. So how can I defer my code until the `posterImage` is set in the cell controller?

Comment: @dasdom I’ve updated the question with my entire `collectionView` method definition.

Comment: Did you connect the posterImage with the imageView in the storyboard?